# Как получить список всех файлов со всех дисков?

Tags: c#

Как можно получить все что есть файлы на компе (вот к примеру как в Directory.GetFiles только вместо одной паки все )

Comment: Use the recursion, Luke!

Comment: @PinkTux: У Windows файловая система не имеет общего корня, в отличие от POSIX-систем. Так что придётся ещё и итерировать по буквам дисков. А ещё поддерживаются сетевые диски (`\\host\sharename\path`), и тома без назначенной буквы (``\\?\Volume{guid}\path``).

Comment: @VladD, не понял - что-то мешает получить список нужных ресурсов и пройтись по ним рекурсивно?

Comment: @PinkTux: Да. Например, я не вспомню сходу библиотечную функцию, которая даст мне все доступные сетевые тома. Так что вопрос нетривиален.

Comment: Вопрос таки про "файлы на компе", а не про всё, что видно с компа.

Comment: @Monk: Тогда обратный случай — вы можете примонтировать сетевой ресурс как диск со своей буквой, файлы на этом диске не находятся «на компе». И это ещё я не вспоминаю про reparse points.

Comment: @VladD, пока сетевой ресурс изображает из себя локальный диск - вполне допустимо. Впрочем, монитриуемые сетевые ресурсы по моему системой отображаются и обрабатываются отдельно. Хотя, за всякий разный софт для этих дел не уверен =)

Comment: @Monk: Допустим, что допустимо (хотя я что-то не уверен). А что делаем с томами без буквы? Вы можете убрать назначенную букву у тома.

Comment: @VladD, слабо представляю, как с этим работает Windows, да и не сталкивался ни разу с этим делом. Так что, если автор не пишет манагер для дисков в Windows - думаю не критично.

Comment: @Monk: Ну, не наше дело додумывать ограничения за ТС. Наберите на вашей машине в комстроке `mountvol`, наверняка покажет какой-нибудь скрытый раздел.

Comment: @VladD, так ваша команда дает вполне валидные адреса для таких дисков, по которым вполне можно запрашивать файлы.

Comment: @Monk: У меня вот сейчас выдаёт: http://pastebin.com/wrgsemhZ (обратите внимание на первый диск)

Comment: @VladD, это уже только к WinAPI, ибо UNC в dotNet не поддерживается нормально.

Answer (score 3):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public static string[] GetFiles(
    string path,
    string searchPattern,
    SearchOption searchOption
)
```

Позволяет указать `AllDirectories` - со всеми подпапками.

---

Если нужно прямо все файлы с компьютера, то выгоднее будет использовать 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(
    string path,
    string searchPattern,
    SearchOption searchOption
)
```

Он в реальном времени отдает файлы, а не пытается прочитать сразу всё.